# How to add rivers in FloPy?

Tags: python, model, raster, flopy

I am working on a steady-state problem and I have a raster with head data values for all rivers.I have to add this to my FloPy code (MODFLOW 6) so I've seen the RIV package and DRN with the hope to find a variable I can use to add the data from my raster (read data values as an array using GDAL) but no answers yet. Haven't found any examples as a guide for now.

I've been thinking to add it as STRT in the IC package, having STRT for rivers in the first layer (I did this for the heads of another layer). But I'm not quite sure, is that okay? Is that the right way, any suggestion to do it, please?

Also, what values should one put to say that there are no heads in a layer?

Clearly, I'm a newbie :p Thank you in advance :).

Comment: The `strt` variable of the IC package specifies the head values for all cells in your model at the start of your simulation. When you say "head data values for all rivers", do you mean river stages or are you talking about groundwater heads? If you are trying to add river cells to your model you need to use the river package and specify stage, conductance, and river bottom elevation for each cell in the `stress_period_data` variable: https://github.com/modflowpy/flopy/blob/develop/flopy/mf6/modflow/mfgwfriv.py

Comment: Yes! River stages. What I'm a bit confused is that I have an intersection done with the shape of the rivers and the surface of the layer but I don't know how to specifically add all that pixel selection from the intersection into the package. I've seen a couple of examples but apparently they use a time series file so the stages and bottom are not directly read from pixel values like in my problem. Can I put the intersection as a raster, read it as an array and add it to the package or something similar? Thank you!

Comment: Again, you're going to need to pass the raster data in as a list of tuples to the `stress_period_data` variable of the RIV package in the format `[(cellid, stage, cond, rbot, aux, boundname), ...]`. Take a look at the input instructions for the RIV package I linked in my first comment. The best way to learn how to pass the correct data in the right format is to look at the docstrings within the code you're using.